# IBM Watson Assistant: How to store any kind of input?

Tags: ibm-cloud, entity, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I want to use slots to store a piece of user information inside a variable. This user Information can be anything. Could be a long sentence or just one word or something like bullet points or a numbered list. Really whatever.

However, using slots I always need Watson to check for something and if that’s present it will be stored in a variable.

So I guess I have to create a pattern based entity?
How would this pattern look like?

Comment: You can put the entire `input.text` into a context variable.

Comment: @chughts This seems not to work for me :( it just saves "input.text" to the $variable and it skips the slot. So there is no 'If not present, ask' text displayed. Hopefully you get what I mean?  

I have 2 slots - first one is clearly defined and if not present the bot asks for it - then I need the bot to jump to the second slot and provide the 'if not present ask' text. then user can input whatever he wants and that get stored to a variable

Comment: @chughts Maybe you have an idea, however, many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this doc page from Watson Assistant about [expressions for accessing objects](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language). One of the global variables is **input**. `input.text` gives you whatever was provided by the user. You can store that in a context variable or process it and only keep parts of it.

[Pattern-based entities](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-patterns) only help if you are looking for something specific in the input. It could be used to find, e.g., an email address or an URI because they adhere to some patterns. As said, for capturing the entire input, just access the global input object and access its text part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! @data_henrik I tried it, there is just one problem for me. I have 2 slots in the node. The second one is the one I used your input.text  - but as soon as the node is activated it saves literaly "input.text" to the $variable and therefore it is already present after providing the answer to my first slot. And therefore user doesn't get asked the if not present question for the second slot. Do you have any clue what to do?

Comment: Have you used `input.text` in an expression? Assign `<? input.text ?>`. See here for an example https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime-spell-check#dialog-runtime-spell-check-how-it-works

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik I forgot to set the variable - now the updating with real content works. I created a new test skill to test it there. I have edited my question - maybe you have an idea how to fix the problem. It still skips the second slot and stores input from slot one to second slot variable - I linked images that will explain better than I can

Comment: @Seb Your updated question is different from the first one. Change it back and open a new question (for readability - the answers are not just for you, but all readers). Please mark this one answered and upvote.